# Send email to Google contact group with Inbox

Tags: google-contacts, inbox-by-gmail

Is it possible to send an email to a [Google Contact Group](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30970?hl=en) from Inbox? In Gmail you could type the name of a group to automatically add all group members as recipients, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is there no way to do this now?

Comment: I believe the option still exists. Kindly check the below link for details,https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30973?hl=en

Comment: You have to read the question properly. Again this question is about Google Inbox, **not** Gmail.

Comment: I still can't see how to do it. I miss this feature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019

Answer (score 8):

It still isn't a feature in Inbox, unfortunately.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/inbox$20group$20email/gmail/U-L6Qsj68gw/oEv7uxiBvuEJ